# Prove that $T(W^{\bot}) \subset W^{\bot}$ where $T$ is unitary operator and $T(W) \subset W$

Tags: linear-algebra

Lets say $T$ is unitary operator and $T(W)\subset W$, where $W$ is a linear subspace of finite dimensional space $V$.

Prove that $T(W^{\bot}) \subset W^{\bot}$, where $W^{\bot}$ is a subspace orthogonal to subspace $W$.

I was trying to do it like this.
Let $w^{\bot} \in W^{\bot}$ we have to show that
$\langle w, Tw^{\bot} \rangle = 0$ where $w \in W$.

But I don't where do I have to use the fact that $T$ is unitary.

Answer (score 1):

Since $T$ is unitary, $\ker T=\{0\}$. Hence, $T|_W:W\to W$ is a linear isomorphism.

This means that every $w\in W$ can be written $w=Tw'$ for some $w'\in W$. What does this mean for $\langle w,Tu\rangle$ where $w\in W$ and $u\in W^\perp$?

Comment: How do we know that ker$T = {0}$

Comment: Because $T$ is unitary, $\|Tx\|=\|x\|$ for all $x\in V$. Does this help?

Comment: Of course! Now it's easy. Would you take a look?
Since $T$ is isomorphism we have
$\langle w, Tu \rangle = \langle Tw^', Tu \rangle = \langle w^, u \rangle = 0$

Answer (score 0):

We know if $W$ is subspace of inner product space $V$, then if $$T(W) \subset W$$ then,
$$T^*(W^{\bot}) \subset  W^{\bot} $$
So, for any $w\in W$ and any $w^{\bot} \in W^{\bot}$, we have,
$$ \langle w,T^*(w^{\bot} )\rangle=0$$
$$\langle Tw,w^{\bot}\rangle=0$$
$$\langle TTw,Tw^{\bot}\rangle=0$$
And we know $T$ is unitary operator and $T(W) \subset W$ , so $T$ must be an isomorphism from $V$ to $V$, so,
$$TTw=w'$$
for some $w' \in W$
So, $$T(W^{\bot}) \subset W^{\bot}$$
Hence, the proof!